links() function in laravel pagination
my proble when i call pagination on my frontend comes with less than equal sign which is not expect to desplay in my page
t
this is my code
backend
$packageviewpictures = PackageInfo::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(3);
return view('pages.packages.index', compact(['logoInfos','packagescost', 'packageviewpictures']));
this frontend
@if(count([$packageviewpictures]) > 0)
@foreach($packageviewpictures as $packageviewpicture)
 packageimage)}}" alt="">
 
 packageimage)}}" class="magnific">
                            @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        {!! $packageviewpictures->links() !!}
                    </div>

this is my code i was trying to fix
this is my code
$packageviewpictures = PackageInfo::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(3);
return view('pages.packages.index', compact(['logoInfos','packagescost', 'packageviewpictures']));
                            @if(count([$packageviewpictures]) > 0)
                            @foreach($packageviewpictures as $packageviewpicture)
                            
                                
                                    
                                    <img src="{{ asset('>packageimage)}}" alt="">
                                    
                                        <a href="{{ asset('>packageimage)}}" class="magnific"><i></i></a>
                                    
                                
                            

                            @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        {!! $packageviewpictures->links() !!}
                    </div>

